# Set last possible position of textbox caret

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a `textbox` and a `TextChanged` event with it that, whenever a user types something, a backslash will automatically be added to the end of the textbox IF there isn't one already.

This works fine except, if the user places the cursor at the end of the textbox AFTER the backslash and types, it moves the backslash to the left, adds the new text, and then another backslash at the end.

For instance, user enters `C` and `C\` appears. Now, if they click after the `\` and type `a`, `C\a\` appears, when what I want is just `Ca\`.

So I need a way to set the last position of the cursor in the textbox to right before the backslash, if the user tries to set it after the backslash.

Here's the code for the textchanged event:

```
private void batchRootFolderText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!batchRootFolderText.Text.EndsWith("\\"))
    {
        batchRootFolderText.Text = batchRootFolderText.Text + "\\";
    }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty weird behavior or `TextBox` if you ask me. Can you tell why are you doing this? Point is you can do change some times later when user finished (on focus lost or button press), not necessarily after every text changes, while he is not finished yet.

Comment: Yeah it is weird, but the user specifically asked for it to happen every time any text is entered. It would be better if I could just do it at the end when they finally press a button to use that text.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void batchRootFolderText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (!batchRootFolderText.Text.EndsWith("\\")){
        String temp = batchRootFolderText.Text;
        temp = temp.Substring(0, MyString.Length - 1);
        batchRootFolderText.Text = temp + "\\";
    }
}
```

Tried cutting the end of the string off then replacing it?

Comment: This doesn't produce the right behavior. For instance, typing `c` produces `c\`. But if the user than puts the caret to the right of the backslash and types `c` again, `c\\` appears instead of `cc\.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable that will keep track of where the backslash is and "move" it to the end when required:

```
int backSlashIndex = -1;

private void batchRootFolderText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!batchRootFolderText.Text.EndsWith("\\"))
    {
        if(backSlashIndex != -1)
        {
            var fullText = batchRootFolderText.Text;

            var beforeBackslashText = fullText.Substring(0, backSlashIndex);
            var afterBackslashText = fullText.Substring(backSlashIndex + 1, fullText.Length - beforeBackslashText.Length - 1);

            batchRootFolderText.Text = beforeBackslashText + afterBackslashText;
        }

        batchRootFolderText.Text = batchRootFolderText.Text + "\\";
        backSlashIndex = batchRootFolderText.Text.Length - 1;
    }
}
```

Remember to add handling for cases when characters are removed by a user or when a user types the backslash character by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cursor position with the SelectionStart property:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectionstart(v=vs.110).aspx

In the SelectionChanged Event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) you can check, if the caret is at the end of the text and if the text ends with a backslash and adjust the position.

```
if (textBox.SelectionStart == textBox.Length - 1 && textBox.Text.EndsWith(@"\")
    textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.Length - 2;
```

This code should do the work.

Comment: That event is only in WPF (I think), this is for winforms.

Comment: Oh that is correct. Just checked it myself. But you still could implement this in MouseUp and KeyUp events. I think mouse and keyboard should be the only way for the user to change the carets position ;)